# Google Drive Android Integration Sample

Tags: android, google-drive-api

Are there any samples to integrate Google Drive with Android? I'm now using Dropbox and their Android SDK is very easy to integrate. For Google Drive, I found the samples all for web apps not for Android. Can anyone share some Google Drive samples for Android? Thanks!

Comment: This wasn't enough? https://developers.google.com/drive/integrate-android-ui

Comment: I don't think this is what I want. This sample is just for the per-file Drive scope for access to user's files. What I need is to browse, upload, and download files in user's drive folder.

Comment: what you had use for dropbox integration ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) The Android sample uses Google Play Services which I just realized still hasn't launched.

2) While there is an Authorization scope for full drive access https://developers.google.com/drive/scopes#requesting_full_drive_scope_for_an_app but all of the Drive APIs appear to be web based and I don't think a device OAuth token will work, especially with the warning on this page https://developers.google.com/drive/register:

> Important: In the field labeled OAuth Client ID (Required), make sure you use a valid Client ID for web applications or other valid Client ID for service accounts or installed apps. These are listed in the Google APIs Console for your API project in the API Access tab. Do not use the Client ID for Drive SDK, which is reserved for future feature development

A guess would be that they are planning for future device level SDK.

Comment: The Google Play Services are now available

Answer (score 4):

i have an app that creates a file and then shares it with other apps. I use a chooser to let the user decide which app to share with.  Set the file type to "multipart/*" and then
Google Drive can pick it up, and so can Dropbox, EverNote, Bump and lots of others -  all without that annoying authorization crap, which you and your users implicitly did already when those apps were installed on the devicxe

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse ("file://" + filePath));

    intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
    intent.setType("multipart/*");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, text));
```

Comment: Can you send multiple files at one time?

Comment: I haven't tried, but I would imagine you could simply have multiple lines of :  intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse ("file://" + filePath));